# Javascript appendChild checkbox onclick not running

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to create a checkbox.  I want the checkbox to call another function.  The problem is that when the checkbox is created it runs the function and then doesn't run when clicked.

```
var cb = document.createElement('input');
cb.type = 'checkbox';
cb.onclick = newfunction();
cb.name = "done";
cb.value = "done";
theCell.appendChild(cb);
```

How can I fix this so that I can create a checkbox and then have it run functions when clicked.  I am using ie8 and Firefox 8. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are executing `newFunction` instead of assigning it.

Remove the `()`:

```
cb.onclick = newfunction;
```

Alternatively, if you need to pass parameters to `newFunction`, wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
cb.onclick = function(){
    newfunction("something");
};
```

Comment: you beat for just 2 seconds :)

Comment: Thanks James! Q: why is the anonymous function required?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong but you should use it like this:

```
cb.onclick = newfunction;//NO BRACKETS in this case
```

Or

```
cb.onclick = function() { newfunction(); }
```